# GObject warning cannot register exisiting type

Tags: gstreamer, glib, gobject

I'm a GStreamer user/programmer but I had never use GLib directly. Recenty I decided to use GLib for building a simple GObject and take advantages of signal implementation. (I'm a Windows programmer)

I have develop a simple static library with the GObject definition, implementation. The main app link statically with this library and link dinamically with other library linked statically with the first one too.

If I call

DummyObj *dummy = (DummtyObj *) g_object_new(DUMMY_OBJ_TYPE, NULL);

from the main app it works, but if inside the dynamic library I try to build a DummyObj instance with the same function, it fails, in the output I can read

cannot register exisiting type ...
g_once_init_leave_ assertion 'initialization_value != 0' failed
g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_tye)' failed

Instead, if is the dynamic library the first one to call
DummyObj *dummy = (DummtyObj *) g_object_new(DUMMY_OBJ_TYPE, NULL);
after if the main app call this function it fails with the same error.

Is like if the first context? that initialize the object is the only one that can create instances of this kind of objects.

I'm a little bit confused about this. In GStreamer I can create new plugins in my main app, inside other plugins, dynamic libraries, I have never see these errors

I hope I have explained well, the english is not my native language and I think that the issue is not easy to explain.

Thanks a lot

It seems that first call to g_object_new in every context try to register the TYPE in a hash_table. The first one can register the TYPE but the second always fail with the same error. Looking the code I'm not able to detect why the second call try to register again the type... the function check_type_name_I in gtype.c fails but I don't know why g_type_register_static is call in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Before glib 2.32 you were required to initialize the thread system (used by the `g_once_...` family functions) by calling once (and only once) `g_thread_init()`. Furthermore, before glib 2.36 you had to initialize the type system with `g_type_init()`.

Knowing that `g_type_init()`:

1. internally [calls `g_thread_init`](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gobject/gtype.c?id=2.30.0#n4248) by itself, protecting from multiple calls by checking `g_thread_get_initialized()` on glib < 2.32;
2. resolves to a [nop function](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-init) on glib >= 2.36;

I think that you can solve your issue in a backward compatible way by just calling `g_type_init()` at startup.